# AngularJS $resource parameter name

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs, interface

I'm working with a PhP interface. I must interact with this interface to save some data. For instance, to save a Customer, the PhP service wants the data through a POST request in this form

- customer[customer_name] = "name of the customer"
- customer[customer_code] = "code of the customer"
- customer[customer_is_visible] = "whether or not the customer is visible"

I tried to create an AngularJS service to do that:

```
angular.module("app").factory("SaveCustomer", ["$resource", 
    function($resource){
        return $resource("/services/customers/post/", 
                            {
                                customer[customer_name]:'@name',
                                customer[customer_code]:'@code',
                                customer[customer_is_visible]:'@visibility',
                                dtsave:'true'
                            },
                            {
                                save: {
                                       method:'POST'
                                }
                            });
}]);
```

The problem is about the parameters name. Angular doesn't like the square bracket and it says: "Expected : but found [ in customer[custom ..." Can I achieve this task or do I have to modify the PhP interface to interact with? (note that the interface has not been created by me). Thank you.

**EDIT:** I call the service this way:

```
SaveCustomer.save({name:customerName, code:customerCode, visibility:customerIsVisible});
```

Comment: Can you post the line/s where you call to the $resource object ?

Comment: I edited the question. Take a look and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try turning `customer` into an object:

```
angular.module("app").factory("SaveCustomer", ["$resource", 
    function($resource){
        return $resource("/services/customers/post/", 
            {
                customer: { 
                    customer_name: '@name',
                    customer_code:'@code',
                    customer_is_visible:'@visibility'
                },
                dtsave:'true'
            },
            {
                save: {
                    method:'POST'
                }
            }
        );
    }
]);
```

Comment: I need the array notation. The PhP interface would like to receive exactly customer[customer_name]='value', customer[customer_code]='code', customer[customer_is_visible]='value' ecc ecc as parameters"

Comment: thats how PHP will receive it. your browser will send it the way you are expecting it @superpuccio

Comment: How can I call the save function? Is this correct? 
SaveCustomer.save({name:customerName, code:customerCode, visibility:customerIsVisible});

Comment: that looks right, should be the same as before @superpuccio

Comment: Mmh...it doesn't seem to work. Have you ever verified that PhP receives data in the right "array" form passing parameters in your way? I suppose the answer is "yes" :)

Comment: throw a debug script in your php code. This is pretty much how forms pass data to php scripts too

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to define anything in default parameters in $resource object, this code should work (I think so)

```
angular.module("app").factory("SaveCustomer", ["$resource", 
    function($resource){
        return $resource("/services/customers/post/", 
            {
                dtsave:'true'
            },
            {
                save: {
                    method:'POST'
                }
            }
        );
    }
]);
```

And you can call it:

```
SaveCustomer.save({customer: {customer_name:customerName, customer_code:customerCode, customer_is_visible:customerIsVisible}});
```

Comment: i'd still keep them in there to declare what is required by the factory, otherwise a customer could not have one of these three fields, if not all of them